# android layout issue with framelayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I'm trying to add the image view but when I do it has so much space between the top and bottom of the image. I'm using a bottom navigation with fragments. I would like to make the image close to the top with the space. What am I doing wrong with this layout?

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.gershpark.MainActivity">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:contentDescription="main image"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_img_1497698892826" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/main_image"
           />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bot_nav">

        </View>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bot_nav"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            design:itemIconTint='#f8f8f8'
            design:menu='@menu/bot_menu'
          />


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Home Fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.gershpark.HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"/>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like by adding the following it removed the spacing that was there.

android:adjustViewBounds="true"